# Flask - Global Variable is not persisting on page reload

Tags: python, flask, global-variables

I am trying to use a global variable within my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

varGlobal = None
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/api/prepare', methods=['POST'])
def prepare():

    if varGlobal is None:
       varGlobal = "some_val"
    return varGlobal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8989, debug=True)
```

So when my page loads and I hit `api/prepare` I get:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'varGlobal' referenced before assignment`

I want this `varGlobal` to persist as long as my app is running. Even if I reload the page. How can I do this?

Comment: add a line "global varGlobal" just under the prepare function definition

Comment: You assign to the `varGlobal` in `prepare`. So it is **not** a global variable. Use `global varGlobal` as first line in `prepare`. That being said, global variables are usually **not** a good idea.

Comment: Note, you almost certainly don't want to do this anyway, as it won't work properly in production.

Answer (score 0):

I won't mention again the reason of your traceback, that's mainly because you're not using the `global` keyword so the global variable can't be bound properly from your method as other already clarified in the comments/answers.

Now, I'd strongly recommend you to avoid global variables, specially in multithread environments, they are evil. Your code will fail miserably when different threads are being spawned (ie: multiple users).

Instead, i'd suggest you get familiar with some of the flask utils created for this very specific task, like this one http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.app_ctx_globals_class.